# Simpson's Rule for Double Integrals

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, matrices, numerical-methods, simpsons-rule

Simpson's Rule for double integrals:
$$\int_a^b\int_c^df(x,y) \,dx \,dy$$
 is given by
$$S_{mn}=\frac{(b-a)(d-c)}{9mn} \sum_{i,j=0,0}^{m,n} W_{i+1,j+1} f(x_i,y_j) $$
where: $$W= \begin{pmatrix}
1&4&2&4& \ldots&4&1\\
4&16&8&16&\ldots&16&4\\
2&8&4&8&\ldots&8&2\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\\
1&4&2&4&\ldots&4&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
 and where $m$ and $n$ are the subdivisions of the domains along $x$ and $y$ respectively. They are obviously both even.

The proof usually involves applying Simpson's Rule to the first integral $\int_a^bf(x,y)dx=g(x,y)$, then applying it to the second $\int_c^dg(x,y)dy$ thus obtaining the coefficients (or weights) $W$ of $f(x,y)$.

I've thought of an alternative: first we find the area under $f(x_i,y_j)$ where $i$ is a fixed value but $y_j$ goes from $c$  to $d$ using Simpson's Composite Rule and fill the coefficients in a vertical matrix $$ \begin{pmatrix}
1\\
4\\
2\\
4\\
2\\
\vdots \\
4\\
1\\
\end{pmatrix} $$

Similarly for a fixed $j$:
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1&4&2&4&2& \ldots &4&1\end{pmatrix}$$

By multiplying the vertical matrix by the horizontal one we get $W$. I thought of the integral (surface) as a linear combination of the $f(x_i,y_j)$'s, justifying the product of the two matrices as a composition of both iterations of Simpson's rule for each variable. Does any of this make sense? Is there a more formal proof of these statements?

**Also**, can you recommend a textbook or some online resource where I can find more approximations like this one?

Comment: This summation is said to be separable, as it can be split in a pure horizontal pass and a pure vertical one, as the array of coefficients is the tensor product of the vectors. The split scheme can be seen as a numerical equivalent of Fubini's theorem. But, sorry, all of this is obvious.

Comment: So, you are taking a Cartesian product of the composite rule with itself, then.

Comment: This may be an interesting observation if you use software like Maple which makes use of the built in matrix manipulation operations?

Comment: Well, this goes a couple of years late, but could you explore this more? I'm currently trying to implement this but have made no advancements