# Numerically integrate $\int_0^1\int_0^1|f|$

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I need to numerically solve an integral of the form $$\int_0^1\int_0^1|f|.$$ You may assume that $f$ has a first derivative, if it matters.

How should I solve this problem? The scheme should be easy to implement and it does not need to be super sophisticated. However, I've started with $$\frac1{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\left|f\left(\frac{i-1}n,\frac{j-1}n\right)\right|$$ and that gave me unsatisfactory results.

My first thought was to try [Simpson's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule#Composite_Simpson%27s_1/3_rule) in both dimensions (I couldn't find a reference for the formula in 2d; the one described in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1319892/47771) seems wrong, since no midpoint is evaluated ...).

Comment: Techniques for numeric integration seems a pretty wide topic. One technique is just to randomly sample points $(x,y)\in[0,1]^2$ and take the average of $|f(x,y)|.$ But your technique of picking a specific set of $n^2$ points is okay, too. It really depends on what you know about $f.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If it helps, the particular functions I want to integrate are in eq. (3) and (7) of [this paper](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/w~raananf/projects/kdm/paper.pdf#page=3) for $\Omega=[0,1)^2$.

Comment: Other than that, the 3-dimensional version of the trapezoid rule seems like it will be slightly better than the simple form you've got. But I'm not sure what that $3$-d form is.